# With networks, how to find first node(s) in a DiGraph

Tags: networkx

Using networks, which is the direct way to find the first node on a directed graph.

There might be more than one and there are not isolated nodes. 
The first nodes I mean the nodes without ancestors.

Best regards and thank you in advance,
Pablo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [in_degree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.in_degree.html). A node with no edges pointing to it will have an in_degree of 0.

```
# make dummy graph
nodes = np.arange(10)
edges = [np.random.choice(nodes, 2) for a in range(10)]

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# find the nodes whose in_degree is 0
[node for node, in_degree  in G.in_degree if in_degree==0]
```